# Are there any presently active OS whose base is neither Windows nor UNIX

Tags: windows, unix, operating-system

The only non UNIX OS is Windows. Rest all OS are UNIX based. Like android, iOS, Mac OSX, chrome OS, Linux OS, Solaris have all their base as UNIX.

So my question is that whether there are any OS's which are non Window as well as non UNIX.

Comment: There are a variety of operating systems for special purpose computers like embedded systems.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that springs to mind is IBM's OS/2, now known as eComStation. Discounting hobby operating systems, there aren't really many others being actively used or developed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are... "OpenVMS, formerly from DEC, is still under active development by Hewlett-Packard. Yet other operating systems are used almost exclusively in academia, for operating systems education or to do research on operating system concepts. A typical example of a system that fulfills both roles is MINIX, while for example Singularity is used purely for research."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system#Other

Answer (score 2):

There are a few older platforms not based on UNIX or NT, but the only notable one  running on today's production hardware without silly hacks (i.e. not some legacy/hobby OS) would be [QNX](http://www.qnx.com). It is used, for example, in the Blackberry 10 OS.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the ones in most active use, according to my experience, in no particular order:

- **z/OS** used on IBM Mainframes.
- **OpenVMS**. Used on VAX and Alpha processors. (may not be appropriate for your list as kernel shares some similarities with Windows due to [Dave Cutler](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-client/windows-nt-and-vms-rest-story) and other engineers who took with them design ideas from VMS to Windows NT when the latter was first conceived)
- **IBM i**. Formerly known as OS/400.
- **NonStop OS**. (Tandem)

(I've only listed what I think of as *general purpose* OSes, not very specialized ones for embedded systems and such)